# How to export SD file with metadata?

Tags: export, chemistry, metadata

Despite the fact that Mathematica (V13.2) is able to import an SD file with corresponding metadata for each structure, e.g.

```
Import["ExampleData/alkanes.sdf", {{"Molecule", "Metadata"}}]
```

I was not successful when exporting a set of Molecules[] together with some data. Attempts like this one

```
Export["test.sdf", {Molecule["methane"], Molecule["propane"]}, "SDF", "MetaData" -> {<|"name" -> "Methan"|>, <|"name" -> "Propan"|>}]
```

seem to work, but the the resulting file (or string) doesn't include any metadata. I've tried several variants, such as

```
ExportString[{{Molecule["methane"], Molecule["propane"]}, "MetaData" -> {<|"name" -> "Methan"|>, <|"name" -> "Propan"|>}}, "SDF"]
(* $Failed *)
```

or

```
ExportString[{{Molecule["methane"], Molecule["propane"]}, {<|"name" -> "Methan"|>, <|"name" -> "Propan"|>}}, "SDF"]
(* $Failed *)
```

Unfortunately, the documentation is silent on this point.

Any comments?

Comment: In exporting jpg and other file formats I encountered the same problem. t first I simply used exiftool to add metadata. Trying Mathematica it was not possible to add metadata, perhaps because some entries  are not editable. Then I found out, that the import with metadata allows to edit the metadata and to export them. Its all very nebulous around Export filters.

Answer (score 5):

When exporting multiple elements for a file, you want to include them all together in the first argument and not place some of them at the end like options.  That's why your first `Export` doesn't work.

Something like this does the trick

```
ExportString[{mols, meta}, {"SDF", {"Molecule", "Metadata"}}]
```

You could also specify the export elements using a list of rules:

```
mols = {Molecule["methane"], Molecule["propane"]};
meta = {<|"name" -> "Methan"|>, <|"name" -> "Propan"|>};

ExportString[{"Molecule" -> mols, "Metadata" -> meta}, {"SDF", "Rules"}]
```

Or put the information inside the molecules:

```
ExportString[{Molecule["methane", 
   MetaInformation -> <|"name" -> "Methan"|>], 
  Molecule["propane", 
   MetaInformation -> <|"name" -> "Propan"|>]}, "SDF"]
```

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you very much Jason!